# updating both object and key dynamically in Firestore cloud Doc

Tags: javascript, object, google-cloud-firestore

I'm updating a firestore document that contains multiple objects. Here is the document structure:

```
2019: { // each key is month and value is number of projects submitted each month
    0: 12, 
    1: 15, 
    2: 5, 
    3: 5, 
    4: 200, 
    5: 15, 
    6: 12, 
    7: 15,
    8: 215,
    9: 15, 
    10: 12, 
    11: 15,
},
2020: {
    0: 3, 
    1: 100, 
    2: 5, 
    3: 75, 
    4: 200, 
    5: 15, 
    6: 12, 
    7: 15,
    8: 215,
    9: 15, 
    10: 13, 
    11: 200,
}
```

I can update the specific value manually like this:

```
2019.2: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) //changing the value of March 2019
```

I can't change it dynamically. I'm trying this:

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear().toString()
var month = new Date().getMonth().toString()


[year].[month]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
```

I tried to use []s and ``s but they didn't work. Here is the full function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.projectAdded = functions.firestore.document('projects/{projectId}').onCreate(doc => {

    const project = doc.data();
    // Get a new write batch
    var batch = admin.firestore().batch();

    // Update count of 'all' Category doc in categories
    var allCat = admin.firestore().collection("categories").doc("all");
    batch.update(allCat, {
        All: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        [project.category]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
    });

    // Update count of 'user Category' doc in categories
    var userCat = admin.firestore().collection("categories").doc(project.authorId);
    batch.update(userCat, {
        All: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        [project.category]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
    });

    // Update count of 'user projects' doc in Users
    var userQ = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(project.authorId);
    var year = new Date().getFullYear().toString()
    var month = new Date().getMonth().toString()
    batch.update(userQ, {
        projectsAdded: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        [year]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        `${year}.${month}`: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),       
    });

    return batch.commit().then(function () {
        console.log("Adding categories")
    })
        .then(doc => console.log('Categories Added'));

});
```

Is there any way I can access the object and it's key dynamically at the same time.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show more completely the code that does and does not work the way you expect?

Comment: I'd expect something like `\`${year}.${month}\`: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` to do the trick, but otherwise we'll indeed need to see a bit more code to make sense of what's happening.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried it but it didn't work. I have included the whole function above.

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Is there an error message? Is anything relevant being logged?

Comment: If use your code, vs code shows following 5 errors:
Property assignment expected.
',' expected.
Argument expression expected.
Declaration or statement expected.
Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: If I use mine, [year].[month], vs code shows following 4 errors:
':' expected.
Identifier expected.
',' expected.
',' expected.

Comment: creating a new variable worked:  var yearMonth = `${year}.${month}` .............  [yearMonth]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1), .......... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To solve that problem, first create a variable with the final value of what you expect, and then, just assign it as follows:

```
{[variable]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment (1)}
```

That way, you will not be passing literal string, but the value of your variable as the object's key.